# Is a reactive web UI to an SQL Server possible? If yes, how?

Tags: sql-server, linux, user-interface

The SQL Server is a given.

I need to create a web UI that accesses the DB and refreshes itself automatically when the DB data changed, regardless of how it changed. This should be done without constant DB polling on the side of the UI.

I saw such a UI done in Java. Nevertheless it reacts only to changes originating from this particular Java UI. Data changes done in some external DB client, like SQL Server Management Studio, for instance, do not appear in the said Java solution.

Is it possible for a web UI to react to all changes, irrespective of their origin?

Ideally the UI should reside on a Linux server and should use Bootstrap. The SQL Server runs in a Windows environment in the same LAN.

If it's possible, what technology stacks would you recommend?

Thank you.

Comment: in .net you could use query notifications but I dont think they have a java implementation

Comment: Thank you. It does not have to be Java.Could this .NET solution work on a Linux OS? Would a .NET UI sense updates made from the outside world?